# Why was there frost on the inside of my windshield?

Tags: ice

I usually start my car remotely and let it warm up before I leave for work.
This morning I forgot to start my car beforehand, so I had to scrape the ice off the windows. I was surprised to find frost on the *inside* of the windshield.  This has never happened to me before. As I have no actual education in physics, can someone explain to me?

Answer (score 0):

The warm steam inside the car undergoes [deposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deposition_(phase_transition)) as it come into touch with the windshield. For this to happen, the humidity inside the car cannot be too low.

Comment: Not sure it goes straight from gas to ice.  You get fog (liquid) on the inside of  the window in cold weather.  But this may be right.  I did not down vote.

Answer (score 0):

It is air on the inside and outside and a cold window.  Inside frist is not as common as inside of the car is protected (warmer).  Inside also does not get rained or snowed on.